# Strange flex module behavior.Module become null when add a little nonsense code

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

When code like this

```
moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY,function(e:ModuleEvent):void{
    var module:Object=moduleInfo.factory.create();
    var elem:IVisualElement=module as IVisualElement;
    isModuleLoaded=true;
});
```

We can see the var module and elem are not null.

[check debug result](http://tonylee.name/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/success.jpg)

But when we add a little nonsense code

```
moduleInfo.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY,function(e:ModuleEvent):void{
    var module:Object=moduleInfo.factory.create();
    var elem:IVisualElement=module as IVisualElement;
    if (elem is IGuipModule){
    }
    isModuleLoaded=true;
});
```

the var module and elem become null.

[check debug result](http://tonylee.name/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/fail.jpg)

So,what's wrong???